How does the context of John 6: 37 -45 contribute to the interpretation of ἑλκύω (helkúō -draw, pull) in terms of God's initiative in salvation?
Exploring the term in its broader biblical context may help clarify how this drawing works and its theological implications.
Text: (NET)

No one can come to me unless the Father who sent me draws him, and I
will raise him up at the last day (John 6:44)
And I, when I am lifted up from the earth, will draw all people to
myself (John 12:32)


@ Sam - Are you trying to teach here by asking a question that you already have an answer to? Or are you sincerely seeking help?

The purpose of this post is to encourage discussion and deeper exploration of biblical texts. While I may have some thoughts on the topic, I genuinely want to hear how others interpret the context of John 6:37-45, especially in light of the term ἑλκύω (helkúō) — a text often taken out of context and used as a proof text for particular doctrines of salvation.

The verb ἑλκύω or  ἑλκω (according to BDAG) occurs only eight times in the NT and its meaning is two-fold:

to move an object from one area to another in a pulling motion, pull, eg, John 21:6, 11, Acts 16:19, 21L30, James 2:6
to draw a person in the direction of values for inner life, draw, attract, eg, John 6:44, 12:32.

In both the latter cases, the sense is of God influencing the minds of people in such a way as to implant the impulse to want to know and serve God as recorded in various places such as:

Phil 2:13 - For it is God who works in you to will and to act on behalf of His good purpose.
John 6:44 - “No one can come to Me unless the Father who sent Me draws him, and I will raise him up at the last day.
John 12:32 - And I, when I am lifted up from the earth, will draw everyone to Myself.”
Rom 2:4 - Or do you disregard the riches of His kindness, tolerance, and patience, not realizing that God’s kindness leads you to repentance?
Rom 5:6, 8 - For at just the right time, while we were still powerless, Christ died for the ungodly. ... But God proves His love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.
Eph 2:4, 5 - But because of His great love for us, God, who is rich in mercy, made us alive with Christ even when we were dead in our trespasses. It is by grace you have been saved!
1 John 4:19 - We love because He first loved us.

That is, God takes the initiative in our salvation.  This is one of the few cases in theology that is relatively uncontroversial.  (The controversial part is what happens next and our response - but that is another question.)

'God takes the initiative in salvation'. Up-voted +1.

Since everyone has already defined the word for drawing, I will add that this can be seen in the O.T. as the eastern wind. The presence of God resides in the west, leaving the eastern gate open. The east is symbolic of outer darkness and in sin (Babylon symbolic of Hell and captivity) where God's people were sent out of God's presence and into captivity, where by the blowing of the eastern wind (Holy Spirit) influences people to travel out of the east (sin) and to the west (think Magi) and enter through the eastern gate into the presence of God. The movement of people traveling from east to west is synonymous with repentance. The Holy Spirit goes before us, drawing us and guiding us into God's dwelling space. The eastern wind shows us the direction.

@Bliff - Appreciate the symbolic interpretation you’ve shared, particularly the imagery of the eastern wind and the movement from east to west in the Old Testament. However, could you focus specifically on the term ἑλκύω (helkúō) in John 6:44, and its exegetical or theological aspects? How this term helps us understand God’s initiative in salvation in the context of John 6:37-45 and how these verses shape our understanding of the Father’s 'drawing' and what it implies about salvation?

@Sam - without making a complete different answer, the word can be used as an attraction. But either way the answer ventures directly into theological territory. If God attracts us or whatever word is used whether it's influences, draws, pulls, attracts, encourages, the interpretation remains the same. There is a supernatural influence that is action based to save people, directing them specifically to the work accomplished on the cross. So the symbolism of my answer fits perfectly, even though it's theological, which your question does require theological implications

@Bliff - Thanks. I can see your emphasis on the supernatural influence of God in drawing people to salvation: Jesus spoke to Nicodemus about the work of the Holy Spirit (John 3); Paul’s encounter with Jesus on the road to Damascus; Lord opened Lydia’s heart (Acts 16); Cornelius (Acts 10). I’ve also had a drastic encounter myself. However, biblically, these examples are just part of the larger picture of how God 'draws' people to Himself.  (to continue)

(continue) - Jesus Himself proclaimed the gospel; the disciples were instructed to do the same, but with the power of the Holy Spirit; and Paul did - "Our gospel came to you not only in word, but also in power and in the Holy Spirit and with full conviction." To fully understand the passage in question, it’s important to study it in a broader context to avoid any biased interpretation or application. Doctrine is necessary, but not necessarily perfect or saves; the Word of God is life and saves.

I fully agree with everything you just said. I also want to apologize for my first comment,  "Are you trying to teach here by asking a question that you already have an answer to? Or are you sincerely seeking help?" There is another Sam on here that was doing that. I realized that you are not the same guy. My apologies again.

@Blif - No worries at all, I really appreciate your thoughtful response and the great discussion! I always enjoy engaging with others on these important topics. Feel free to check out more of my thoughts on my blog: samwithbible.org. Looking forward to continuing the conversation!

In the Gospels and the book of Acts, we see how God ἑλκύω (helkúō - "draw, pull") individuals in various ways to Jesus, the gospel, and salvation. Examples include Zacchaeus being drawn while on a sycamore tree; Nathanael led by Philip; Cornelius through an angel; Paul on the road to Damascus; Lydia, whose heart the Lord opened; the Samaritan woman at the well; and the disciples of Jesus. There are also instances of personal callings in the Old Testament. God is the one who initiates our salvation, often employing a variety of ways to 'pull and draw' individual people to Jesus. All these individuals responded to the call of God and remained faithful to the end, except Judas, who betrayed Jesus.
However, the term ἑλκύω (helkúō - "draw, pull") in the context of John 6:37-45 takes on particular significance.
ἑλκύω (helkúō) in the context of John 6:37-45
In this passage, Jesus addresses the Israelites as a nation, drawing them to Himself—not merely for outward religious observance, but to turn and serve Him wholeheartedly by believing in the Gospel. This also applies to all who are drawn to Him. Despite God's initiative, Jesus implies that many of 'His own people' resist and refuse to respond, choosing not to come to Him and thus rejecting the very salvation God offers.
Although Jesus is specifically addressing the Israelites in this passage, the principles of God's drawing and human responsibility apply more broadly. It is important to understand that this passage does not support certain doctrinal interpretations, such as those found in TULIP (see Footnote) or the doctrine of 'once saved, always saved.'
While John 6:44 speaks of the Father drawing specific individuals and group of people to Jesus, John 12:32 expands this to a universal offer of salvation through Jesus' crucifixion. This highlights that although salvation is offered to all, it will be realized only by those who respond and come to Him."
This drawing is potentially efficacious for all, as salvation is offered universally, but it will only be realized by those who respond and come to Jesus. In John 6:39-40, Jesus states that none of those whom the Father draws to Him will be lost, and He will raise them up at the last day. Those who respond and come to Jesus are described as the true Israelites, the ones who are "taught by God" (John 6:45).
It is important to note that the usage of the term ἑλκύω in this context is not a proof text for any specific doctrinal system of salvation, such as TULIP. Rather, it highlights God's initiative in drawing people to Himself and their responsibility to respond. Those who come to Jesus, having been taught by God, are the ones who experience the fullness of God's promise of eternal life.
Furthermore, this ἑλκύω by God does not imply a guaranteed or permanent state of salvation. Jesus clarifies in John 6:47: "I tell you the solemn truth, the one who believes has eternal life." Here, the verb πιστεύων (believing) is in the Present Participle Active, which denotes continuous action or state. This implies that eternal life is granted from the moment of faith in Jesus but remains contingent on continuing in belief. In other words, contrary to the doctrine of 'once saved, always saved,' when ongoing faith ceases, so does the assurance of the promise of eternal life. It is through continued faith and trust in Jesus that one remains united with Him and experiences eternal life (cf. John 5:24)."
In sum:
The term ἑλκύω (helkúō - "draw, pull") signifies that God initiates the Plan of Redemption and our salvation. However, as observed above and seen in Jesus' lament over Jerusalem (Matt. 23:37), this drawing does not imply 'irresistible grace' or the doctrine of 'once saved, always saved.'
Footnote:
TULIP is an acronym representing five points of Calvinist doctrine: Total Depravity (humans are completely fallen and incapable of coming to God on their own), Unconditional Election (God chooses whom to save without regard to individual merit), Limited Atonement (Christ’s atonement is effective only for the elect), Irresistible Grace (those chosen by God will inevitably come to faith), and Perseverance of the Saints (the elect will remain in faith and cannot lose their salvation).
